# Elegant way to validate multidimensional $_POST

Tags: php, validation, multidimensional-array

I have an user input like this: `$_POST['multi']['dim']['form'] = 1.213`.

I want to validate this and at the moment I use this function:

```
public function checkFloat($number, $min = null, $max = null)
{
    $num = filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);

    if($num === false || ($min !== null && $num < $min) || ($max !== null && $num > $max))
        return false;

    return $num;
}
```

But befor calling this function I have to check first that `$_POST['multi']['dim']['form']` is set.

So every call looks like

```
if(isset($_POST['multi']['dim']['form']) && ($num = checkFloat($_POST['multi']['dim']['form']) !== false))
{
    // do something here
}
```

If I do not check first, if the variable is set, PHP will throw a notice.
I noticed the PHP function `filter_input`, but it seems that this is not working with multidimensional `$_POST`.

I thought about a wrapper like

```
function checkFloat($names_of_the_fields,$min,$max)
{
    // check if $_POST[$name][$of][$the][...] is set

    // make the validation
}
```

But I'm not sure how to pass the `$name_of_the_fields`.

Here I thought of an array `$arr['key1']['key2'][...]`. but since I not know how deep this is, i have to run a lot `is_array` checks. Or I pass an array like `$arr = ['key1','key2',...]`.

**Is there a nice and clean way to do this? Should I ignore the notice?

Or should I go on with `if(isset.. && checkFloat...)`?**

Changing the form and using `eval()` is not an option.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1:** 
`is_array($var)` is not that slow, if `$var` is setted. So it would be ok, if I use a function that checks structure. But the question is still, if this is a good way, or if there is a better (maybe faster) way to do this.

Comment: What makes you think `is_array` is slow?  I just did a short benchmark and managed 10mil `is_array` calls per second.  Took just as long to do 10mil `is_string` calls.  Maybe you're confusing the performance of `count` and `is_array`?  `count` *is* slow, `is_array` is not.

Comment: compared to `isset` i think `is_array` is slow. about 20 times. Problem is, if I call the field directly I can wrtie `if(isset($arr['foo']['bar']['baz']) && isValid($arr['foo']['bar']['baz']))`. If not I think I have to pass an array to the function and have to do some `is_array` calls to go  through the structure array.

Comment: I just benchmarked **10 million** calls of `isset` vs `is_array` on an array with 10,000 elements.  `is_array() = 1.01 sec`, `isset() = 0.65 sec`.  Calling `isset` may be faster, but not anywhere near 20 times faster (it's only 1.5 times faster).

Comment: you right. I tested with an not setted variable.

Comment: 1 million calls of `is_array` take 0.95s while 1 million calls of `isset` takes only 0.05s (if the variable is not setted)

Comment: can the downvoters please explain why they voted down..?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Why do you mind such trifling difference in performance that does not appear without **10 milion** calls? It becomes nothing when  you decide to use **a very slow script language, PHP**. I recommend you to use C, C++, Java or Scala instead.

Comment: I building a website with lots of user inputs. So I want a fast input validation. I never thought about using C.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Your approach is wrong. See this [slide](http://www.slideshare.net/jignesht/performance-tuning-in-php-presentation)

Comment: What is exactly wrong? From the slides i only get, that I can improve the performance by using opcache / apc. but there is also code optimization. Do I miss something?

Comment: I did all code optimizations that I can... Aren't you satisfied with **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120105/elegant-way-to-validate-multidimensional-post/24124845#24124845)**?

Comment: In addition, I'm always be careful not for causing `E_NOTICE`. So my code with `is_array` is not slow.

Comment: Yes I noticed this. I also like your 1st answer better than the 2nd. I first had a wrong thinking about `is_array`. I deleted my comment about this. I dont know why it was voted down. But I hoped there is something shorter. But pushing ther `isset($_POST[..]...)` into the validations seems to be complexer as it sounds :( at the moment I think it is faster to stay with `if(isset($_POST[..]..) && valid($_POST[..]..))`

Comment: Yes, the improvement of the flexibility causes the trade-off with the performance. You need to agree to some kind of middle ground.

Comment: Time to go to bed zzz

Comment: Yes, I know. I let this question open. Maybe someone have an awesome idea to make this trade-off very cheap.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You'll like it :D

```
function filter_input_simple($type, $name, $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT, $options = FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR) {
    static $vars;
    if (!$vars) {
        $vars = array(
            INPUT_GET    => filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING'),
            INPUT_POST   => file_get_contents('php://input'),
            INPUT_COOKIE => filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_COOKIE'),
        );
        $s = array('&', '&', ';[; ]++');
        foreach ($vars as $t => $var) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach (preg_split("@{$s[$t]}@", $var, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $i) {
                list($k, $v) = explode('=', $i, 2) + array(1 => '');
                $tmp[urldecode($k)] = urldecode($v);
            }
            unset($tmp['']);
            $vars[$t] = $tmp;
        }
        $vars += array(INPUT_REQUEST =>
            $vars[INPUT_COOKIE] + $vars[INPUT_POST] + $vars[INPUT_GET]
        );
    }
    $type = (int)$type;
    $name = filter_var($name);
    if (!isset($vars[$type][$name])) {
        return null;
    }
    return filter_var($vars[$type][$name], $filter, $options);
}
```

Usage:

```
// This function does not use extracted values as $_GET,
// so put QueryString on your browser for testing.
// 
// ?foo[bar][validated_float]=1,234.213

$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 1234,
        'max_range' => 1235,
    ),
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND,
);
var_dump(filter_input_simple(INPUT_GET, 'foo[bar][validated_float]', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, $options));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and testing I came up with this:

I splitted each validation function up into two functions and added a function that checks if an array key exists.

- `validate[Type]Var($val, $options)`: checks if `$val` contains a valid value. (no changes here)
- `validate[Type]Input(&$inputArr,$keys,$options)`: calls `getArrayValue(&array,$keys)` and if the key exists, it calls validate[Type]Val() to validate the value.

In detail:

```
public function getArrayValue(&array,$keys)
{
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if(!isset($array[$key]))
        return null;

    if(empty($keys))
        return $array[$key];

    return $this->getArrayValue($array[$key],$keys);
}

public function validateTypeInput(&$inputArr, $keys, $options = [])
{
    $value = $this->getArrayValue($inputArr, $keys);

    if(isset($value))
        return $this->validateTypeVal($value,$options);
    else
        return null;     // or return anything else to show that the value was invalid 
}
```

The function can be called by
`ValidationClass->validateTypeInput($_POST,['key1','key2','key3'],$options);`
to validate `$_POST['key1']['key2']['key3']`.

*Notice*: I wrote an `validateTypeInput` for each type, because some of them are different. Eg. if you validate checkbox input, you dont want a not setted input to be considered invalid.

Answer (score -1):

It won't validate the *structure* of the data passed to it, but it will ensure that each *item* passes the `checkFloat` function:

```
function validate_info($info) {
    if (is_array($info)) {
        // $info is an array, validate each of its children
        foreach ($info as $item) {
            // If item is invalid, stop processing
            if (validate_info($item) === false) { return false; }
        }

        // If each $item was valid, then this $info is valid.
        return true;

    } else {
        // $info is a single item
        return checkFloat($info, [YOUR_MIN_VAL], [YOUR_MAX_VAL]);
    }
}
```

The function will return true if every item in `$info` returns true for `checkFloat`.  If any value in `$info` returns false, then `validate_info` will return false.  This function uses recursion to check the whole array, regardless of structure.

---

**edit:** This function does use the `is_array` function, but you seem to be mistakenly thinking that the `is_array` function is slow.  The `is_array` function runs in constant time, which can be [verified by checking the PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/standard/type.c#L298).

Answer (score -2):

## Class Definition:

```
/**
 * Object for filter_input_array_recursive().
 */
class FilterObject {

    private $filter;
    private $options;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param int   $filter  same as ones for filter_input().
     * @param mixed $options same as ones for filter_input().
     */
    public function __construct($filter = FILTER_DEFAULT, $options = FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR) {
        $this->filter  = $filter;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public function getFilter() {
        return $this->filter;
    }

    public function getOptions() {
        return $this->options;
    }

}
```

## Function Definition:

```
/**
 * Apply filter_input() recursively.
 * 
 * @param int   $type    INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_REQUEST are supported.
 * @param array $filters Multi-demensional array, which contains FilterObject for each leaf.
 * @return array
 */
function filter_input_array_recursive($type, array $filters) {
    static $recursive_static;
    static $flag_match;
    static $is_not_array;
    static $filter_array;
    static $types;
    if (!$flag_match) {
        /* initialize static variables */
        $types = array(
            INPUT_GET     => $_GET,
            INPUT_POST    => $_POST,
            INPUT_COOKIE  => $_COOKIE,
            INPUT_REQUEST => $_REQUEST,
        );
        $flag_match = function ($v, $f) {
            return (int)(isset($v['flags']) ? $v['flags'] : $v) & $f;
        };
        $is_not_array = function ($v) {
            return !is_array($v);
        };
        $filter_array = function ($v) {
            return !is_array($v) ? $v : false;
        };
    }
    $recursive = $recursive_static;
    if (!$recursive) {
        /* only for first loop */
        $type = (int)$type;
        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('unknown super global var type');
        }
        $var = $types[$type];
        $recursive_static = true;
    } else {
        /* after first loop */
        $var = $type;
    }
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        $isset = isset($var[$key]);
        if (is_array($value)) {
            // apply child filters
            $ret[$key] = filter_input_array_recursive($isset ? $var[$key] : array(), $value);
        } else {
            if (!($value instanceof FilterObject)) {
                // create default FilterObject for invalid leaf
                $value = new FilterObject;
            }
            $filter = $value->getFilter();
            $options = $value->getOptions();
            // check if key exists...
            // true  -> apply filter_var() with supplied filter and options
            // false -> regard as null
            try {
                $ret[$key] = $isset ? filter_var($var[$key], $filter, $options) : null;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $recursive_static = false;
                throw $e;
            }
            if ($flag_match($options, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY | FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)) {
                // differently from filter_input(),
                // this function prevent unexpected non-array value
                if (!is_array($ret[$key])) {
                    $ret[$key] = array();
                }
                // differently from filter_input(),
                // this function prevent unexpected multi-demensional array
                if ($flag_match($options, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)) {
                    // eliminate arrays
                    $ret[$key] = array_filter($ret[$key], $is_not_array);
                } else {
                    // change arrays into false
                    $ret[$key] = array_map($filter_array, $ret[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$recursive) {
        /* only for first loop */
        $recursive_static = false;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

## Usage:

```
$_POST['foo']['bar']['validated_float'] = '1,234.213';
$_POST['foo']['forced_1d_array']        = array('a', array('b'), 'c');
$_POST['foo']['required_1d_array']      = array('a', array('b'), 'c');
$_POST['foo']['required_scalar']        = array('a', array('b'), 'c');
```

When inputs are like this,

```
var_dump(filter_input_array_recursive(INPUT_POST, array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => array(
            'validated_float' => new FilterObject(
                FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT,
                array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'min_range' => 1234,
                        'max_range' => 1235,
                    ),
                    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND,
                )
            ),
        ),
        'forced_1d_array'   => new FilterObject(FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY),
        'required_1d_array' => new FilterObject(FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY),
        'required_scalar'   => new FilterObject,
    ),
)));
```

this snippet will output...

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["bar"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["validated_float"]=>
      float(1234.213)
    }
    ["forced_1d_array"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "c"
    }
    ["required_1d_array"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      bool(false)
      [2]=>
      string(1) "c"
    }
    ["required_scalar"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```